# What is meant by the statement mentioned below?

Tags: citations, academic-writing

" AVOID CIATATIONS IN TITLE"

I just got this remark from an editor after 2 days of an article submission. He has said to avoid citations in title. I have not cited in any title, be it main title or sub-title. I really do not understand this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a reputable journal? That's my first suspicion. I see red flags here. Be sure the journal is legitimate.  If the journal is legitimate, is it possible your citation software has a bug and inserted something 'invisible'? (I've never heard of this.)

Comment: Did you ask the editor for clarification? What type of journal is this? Can you perhaps even tell us which exact journal is involved? Is that quote actually correct, misspelling and all? Can you share the title and subtitle with us? Please [Edit] your question to add more information to make this answerable. (It may turn out to be a better fit on one of our sister sites in the network, but the extra information almost certainly won't hurt in either case, and it may very well help.)

Comment: You misspelt "Citation". Did the editor misspell it also? ----- Are any of your actual citations **just** titles, with no information about when or where the cited article was published or might be found? That's the only thing I can think it means.

Comment: Aha, yes, I think that's it. What Amadeus said. In your bibliography, are some of the titles of your cited references hot linked?

Comment: @Amadeus, I have done the in-text citations in the article with vancouver style of referencing.

Comment: This is quite hard to answer without seeing the actual example.

Answer (score 4):

Confront him or her with the unclarity. The fault could be entirely theirs. People make mistakes all the time. Perhaps the editor meant "quotations".